# XSLT, XPath and InStr

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is there a way to find a node matched on part of a value.

If I have the following:

```
<competition id="100" name="Barclays Premier League"/>
<competition id="101" name="CocaCola Championship" />
<competition id="102" name="CocaCola League 1" />
```

Given the string "Premier League" or even "Prem", how would I match the correct node and get id 100.

I have managed this using for-each and contains, but this is very inefficient and does not work fast enough for our requirements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

String handling is not something XSLT is amazing at but there are a few options.

In this case you might try:

```
//competition[contains(@name,'Prem')]
```

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string) for more options and details

Comment: And if you want just the id then //competition[contains(@name,"Prem")]/@id

Comment: the "//" is probably inadvisable too before anyone else mentions it - I just didn't know any other structure to path on obviously.

Comment: Annakata, I think you're a little bit wrong about the string-handling capabilities of XSLT. Do have a look at my blog where you'll find a few interesting examples to the contrary. :)  Cheers

Comment: @Dimitre - I make that statement in reference to really solid string-feature languages like perl and JS, and with the awkwardness of tasks like string.replace in mind. I love XSLT as much as the next XSLT fanboy :)

Comment: @Annacata, nice to here you're an XSLT fan :) But really, I've done spelling checking, concordance building, solved Tim Bray's Wide Finder in just 22 lines, provided a general LR parser, used it to parse JSON and XPath 2 ... all that in pure XSLT. What other string-processing challenge do we need?

Comment: @dimitre - impressed by spell checking. I would suggest though that just because something is possible doesn't mean it's efficient. You can't tell me search-and-replace in XSLT is elegant. I'd be interested to see how your pure XSLT approach benchmarks vs (e.g.) .net xslt extension arguments.

Comment: @Annacata, it is not the language but the algorithm used. I guess that the XPath 2.0 standard function replace(), which uses RegEx-s will not be very different in efficiency than a .NET extension function. Of course, in .NET one will have to use (for now) a non-MS product, such as Saxon.NET

Answer (score 6):

Use:

**`//competition[contains(@name, 'Prem')]/@id`**

In other situations such functions as: [**starts-with()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-starts-with) or [**ends-with()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-ends-with) (XPath 2.0 only) can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a "matches" function, which uses regular expressions, but this is only available in XSL 2.0.